# access env variables in react frontend with webpack define plugin

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, babel-loader

I have an express app hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk. I have 3 env variables that I set in the configuration settings on AWS.

db=myMongoDbConnectString -express

secretKey=1234 -express

REACT_APP_StripeKey=LiveStripeKey -react

I'm using npm config to access the first 2 and I can use them perfectly in the express application. Im using a webpack define plugin to access the StripeKey in the react frontend but console.log says its undefined. I'm new to webpack so i'm sorry if its something simple.

```
server.js

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const cron = require("node-cron");
var helmet = require("helmet");
var cors = require("cors");
var path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var RateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const antique = require("./routes/antiques");
const users = require("./routes/users");
var payment = require("./routes/payment");
const checkout = require("./routes/checkouts");
const auth = require("./models/auth");
const { User } = require("./models/user");


const app = express();

//getting web token private key
if (!config.get("secretKey")   ) {
  console.error("fatal error jwt private key not defined");
  process.exit(1);
}


//aply limits to all requests
var limiter = new RateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, //15 mins
  max: 100, //limit each ip to 100 requests per window
  delay: 0, //full speed until the max limit
});
app.use(limiter);
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.disable("etag").disable("x-powered-by")


//used to connect to db
mongoose
  .connect(config.get("db"), {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("connected to db..."))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Something went wrong connecting to db..."));

//express built in middleware
app.use(express.json()); //used to parse json body in responce
//app.use(express.static());//used for serving up pictures


//Routes
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))
})

app.use("/api/antiques", antique);
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/auth", auth);
app.use("/api/payment", payment);
app.use("/api/checkouts", checkout);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/build")
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './client')
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: APP_DIR + '/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: BUILD_DIR
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        
                        options: {

                            presets: ['@babel/react'],
                            
                            
                            "plugins": [
                                [
                                  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                                  {
                                    "loose": true
                                  }
                                ],
                                
                                
                              ]
                        },
                       
                    },
                    
                ],
                
                 
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            
        ]
        
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.REACT_APP_StripeKey':
            JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_StripeKey),
        })
    ]
}
```

/client/app.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar.jsx";
import AdminPortal from "./components/adminPortal.jsx";
import Logout from "./components/logout.jsx";
import Home from "./components/home.jsx";
import Login from "./components/login.jsx";
import Antique from "./components/antique.jsx";
import Cart from "./components/cart.jsx";
import auth from "./services/authService.js";
import CheckoutForm from "./components/checkoutForm.jsx";
import NotFound from "./components/notFound.jsx"

class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    this.setState({ user });
  }
  render() {
   
    const stripePromise = loadStripe(
      process.env.REACT_APP_StripeKey
    );
    const { user } = this.state;

    return (
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <NavBar user={this.state.user} />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
              <Route
                path="/profile"
                render={(props) => (
                  <Profile {...props} user={this.state.user} />
                )}
              />
              <Route path="/antique" component={Antique} />
              <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
              <Route path="/checkoutForm" component={CheckoutForm} />
              <Route
                path="/adminPortal"
                render={(props) => {
                  if (!user) return <Redirect to="/login" />;
                  return <AdminPortal {...props} />;
                }}
              />
              <Route path="/*"  component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Elements>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```